# Trouble downloading ADYEN report

Tags: wget, adyen

I'm using this script:

wget -O C:\FlairnetLab\output\x.csv --http-user='[My User]' --http-password='[Password]'  --no-check-certificate https://ca-test.adyen.com/reports/download/MerchantAccount/FlairnetECOM/payments_accounting_report_2021_06_10.csv

But i get no file found response. But if i type the url in the browser using the same credential i can download the file.

Can some help me?

Comment: Are you using the dedicated `report@XXXXXX` api credentials?

Comment: Yes, and the Merchant Report Download role is active. I will be mad..... i can't understand why this is happening. Luke can you download with wget?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely to be the encoding of the credentials (both Adyen-generated `username` and `password` include several special characters).

An option is to generate the base64-encoded string `username: password` with a command line (or with an online generator)

```
# example on Mac
$ echo -n '<username>:<password>' | openssl base64
cmVwb3J0.......5LX4=
```

then pass it in the `Authorization` header

```
# example with wget
wget --header "Authorization: Basic cmVwb3J0.......5LX4=" https://ca-test.adyen.com/reports/download/MerchantAccount/MyMerchantAccount/payments_accounting_report_2021_01_01.csv

# example with curl
curl -H "Authorization: Basic cmVwb3J0.......5LX4=" -X GET https://ca-test.adyen.com/reports/download/MerchantAccount/MyMerchantAccount/payments_accounting_report_2021_01_01.csv
```